# PHP /tmp files disappear in the middle of request - sometimes

Tags: php, debian

So I have an API built with php 7.2 with nginx and php-fpm for uploading files.

When the file is uploaded, there are several steps that are done on a file in /tmp before it gets moved to mounted NAS.

1. check permissions
2. scan for viruses
3. create db record
4. generate thumbnails
   ....
   and at the end copy to NAS.

Files are uploaded one by one in consecutive requests from the frontend. In 99.999% on time, everything goes well, but sometimes a file disappear  in the middle of request. Sometimes on the 2nd step, sometimes on 4th, sometimes on the 5th without any rule. It doesn't matter what the file sizes are, it breaks on 30kb and 200mb files equally and the limits are in GBs. Also, not related to the kind of file. It happens to fail for images, zip, docs...

Here is a screanshot from Graylog of a single request that confirms that the tmp file exists on the start of request and disappears later on.

[image]

Comment: Have your checked, whether your antivirus software is deleting the files? Are there any clean up task for the /tmp directory from the operating system? Can monitor the directory using auditd?

Comment: _“there are several steps that are done on a file in /tmp before it gets moved to mounted NAS”_ - and those steps are performed who, exactly?

Comment: Pretty much thinking what @Yeti said. Maybe try setting the directory to which files are uploaded to a different directory

Comment: I can try setting it to another directory, but it bugs me why it works most of the time, and just sometimes it disappears.

Comment: As far as I know, PHP doesn't have employ automatic garbage collection for its tmp directory. So this is most likely an outside influence

Comment: Tmp files should be removed at the end of request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there's some kind of cleanup script running on your `/tmp` folder, and that's removing whatever file(s) are being processed at the time.

For example, on my ubuntu system there's a daily cron that runs and cleans the folder.

I'd suggest using a different folder, owned by the web server user. This should eliminate the possibility of issues with `/tmp`.

Comment: This is worth trying. It can be done with [upload_tmp_dir](http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir).

Comment: There are no scripts cleaning the /tmp folder, and it happens on 3 different servers, all 100% in our control, but changing the tmp directory to something else did the job.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) of the PHP `tmpfile()` function:

`The file is automatically removed when closed (for example, by calling fclose(), or when there are no remaining references to the file handle returned by tmpfile()), or when the script ends.`

I was encountering this problem, and I realized that I was storing the file handle in a local function variable.  I tried returning the handle from the function, and then the file persisted after the function and was deleted after the script terminated.